# angularjs template location changes per environment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular js app that uses directives.  In my local copy of the code, the location of the templates are {rootsite}/content/html/{view} on my other environments, the location of the templates are {rootsite}/{additionalName}/content/html/{view}.

I want to be able to maintain the code easily, so I don't want to have to change anything between environments.  Is there something in angular that can help?

```
app.directive('directiveName', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/Content/html/pageName.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        multiElement: true,
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course. Use a variable

Comment: set up a global constant `app.constant('PATHS',{root : 'additionalName'})` and inject it into the directive: `app.directive('directiveName', function (PATHS) {`. Then simply write it as: `templateUrl: PATHS.root + '/Content/html/pageName.html',`

Comment: I thought of a variable.  I would rather it be in a config file of some sort.  Something that will not get changed.  Currently my entire app and all directives are in a single file.  I could separate the app declaration and constant into it's own file, but then in the future if any other modules need added, I have to remember to change the constant when deploying.

Comment: if you want to know your root path, you need to get it from backend (PHP? `dirname(__FILE__)`?) But then you would need an asynchronous request

Comment: And the asynchronous request would have a performance hit.  Between this and the constant, I think I would go the constant and separate the app declaration into it's own js file.

Comment: What about adding the root url to the attributes of the directive?

Comment: can you describe the issue with attributes? Adding strings is 'concatenation' - with a `+`

Comment: I don't know that I have an issue with the putting the root url in attributes.  I suggested it to see if anyone had any thoughts on it.

Comment: well I can only imagine something like `<img ng-src="{{root}}/some/path/image.png"/>`, where you will set `$scope.root` in your (_main_) controller with something like `= PATHS.root;`

Comment: Depends on you build process. A crude solution is to add a global script file, say `config.js`,  with `var templateDir = '....';`. Not a good practice but effective